# Function table(x, y) compatible with R base language and native pipe

Tags: r, function, pipe, pivot-table

I am looking to develop a `tab(x, y)` or `tab(d, x, y)` function compatible with r base language (`table(d$x, d$y)`) and native pipe (`d |> table(x, y)`).

Native pipe compatible function:

```
tab1 <- function(d, x, y){
  eval(substitute(table(d$x, d$y)))
}

mtcars |> tab1(cyl, vs)
# or
tab1(mtcars, cyl, vs)
```

R base:

```
tab2 <- function (x, y) {
  result <- table(x, y)
  result
}

tab2(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs)
```

What should I add to the tab1 function so that the command `tab1(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs)` does not return an error message (sometimes, using a pipe compatible function, the name of the dataframe is repeated incorrectly)?

I would like to get a function (`tab(d, x, y)` or `tab(x, y)`) that works with these commands:

```
tab(mtcars, cyl, vs) # it's tab1 function 
mtcars |> tab(cyl, vs) # it's tab1 function  
tab(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs) # doesn't work with tab1 function
```

and ideally also with:

`tab(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs) # it's tab2 function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this definition the examples below all work as in `table`.  Note that `table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$cyl)` does not show names so `tab3` does not either in those cases.  (If `table` in `tab3` were replaced with `qtab` from collapse then it would show names.)

```
tab3 <- function(d = parent.frame(), x, y, ...) {
  if (missing(y)) eval(substitute(table(d, x)))
  else eval(substitute(table(x, y)), d)
}
    
tab3(x = mtcars$vs, y = mtcars$cyl)
tab3(mtcars, vs, cyl)
tab3(mtcars$vs, mtcars$cyl)
tab3(mtcars, mtcars$vs, mtcars$cyl)
```

The code could be simplified if d were last:

```
tab4 <- function(x, y, d = parent.frame(), ...) {
  eval(substitute(table(x, y)), d)
}

tab4(x = mtcars$vs, y = mtcars$cyl)
tab4(vs, cyl, mtcars)
tab4(mtcars$vs, mtcars$cyl)
tab4(mtcars$vs, mtcars$cyl, mtcars)
```

Perhaps you could just use xtabs.  All of these work and do show names.

```
xtabs(~ vs + cyl, mtcars)
xtabs(~ mtcars$vs + mtcars$cyl)
xtabs(~ mtcars$vs + mtcars$cyl, mtcars)
```

Comment: I don't understand "If table in tab3 were replaced with qtab from collapse then it would show names". What is `qtab`? How can I show names?

Comment: `library(collapse); tab3 <- function(d = parent.frame(), x, y, ...) {
  if (missing(y)) eval(substitute(qtab(d, x)))
  else eval(substitute(qtab(x, y)), d)
}`